# can't set path for javac

Tags: path, javac

I've put in an embarrassing amount of time reading threads here and elsewhere, I cannot compile HelloWorldApp.java

Using Windows 7

the location of the script is C:\Users\Phil\Desktop

the location of javac is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin

In Environment Variables, in both User and System Variables, I have clicked NEW, and given the "Variable Name" as javac and "Variable Value" as `

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin;

`

I have tried to make this work based on the 2 different ways here (to no avail): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/

I am failing to set a path, or tell computer where to find it from within cmd.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have solved my problem:

In Environment Variables, the "Variable Name" must be: `PATH`

The Variable value is: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin`

Now It works!

Answer (score 0):

just you have to do set temporary path set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45;
or
change your Environment variable path
to
variable name=%path%
variable value:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45;
then open cmd and run javac command to check